# curve windings proof

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a step in the following proof for the equality of
$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-a}=2\pi in$, for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ which I don't understand.

Given $\gamma:[\alpha,\beta] \rightarrow \mathbb{C},$
 we can write:
$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-a}=\int_\alpha^\beta\frac{\gamma'(s)ds}{\gamma(s)-a}$

Then with  $\alpha\leq t \leq \beta$
we get, 
$h(t):=\int_\alpha^t\frac{\gamma'(s)ds}{\gamma(s)-a}$,
from which  $h'(t)=\frac{\gamma'(t)dt}{\gamma(t)-a}$ follows.

Now my notes tell me that as a consequence it follows: $\frac{d}{dt}e^{-h(t)}(\gamma(t)-a)=0$. I don't understand how they get there. Anyone could help me?

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a $C^1$ curve $b\to c$ not passing through $a$ then $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-a} = \log_1(c-a)-\log_2(b-a)$ for some branches $\log_1,\log_2$ of $\log$. Thus if $b= c$ then $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-a} = 2i k \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $h(t) = \int_\alpha^t \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)-a}ds$

Differentiating with respect to $t$, we have

$$h'(t) = \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}$$

$$\gamma'(t)-(\gamma(t)-a)h'(t)=0$$

Multiply by the integrating factor $\exp(-h(t))$,

$$\gamma'(t)\exp(-h(t))-(\gamma(t)-a)h'(t)\exp(-h(t))=0$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{d\exp(-h(t))(\gamma(t)-a)}{dt}=0$$

by product rule.

Answer (score 2):

If $h(t)=\int_a^t \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)-a}\,ds$ where $\gamma'(s)$ is continuous and $\gamma(s)\ne a$ for $s\in [a,t]$, then clearly the fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees that  $h'(t)=\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}$.

Now, let $g(t) = e^{-h(t)}(\gamma(t)-a)$.  Taking the derivative of $g(t)$ reveals

$$g'(t)=-h'(t)g(t)+\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}g(t)=g(t)\left(-\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}+\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}\right)=0$$

as was to be shown!